# Spring deployment settings openshift

Tags: java, spring, openshift

I have a problem that is driving me nuts for three days.

I was deployed spring-eap6-quickstart code according to tutorial on the OpenShift account. I'm configured debug options and I'm synchronized eclipse workspace with OpehShift server - everything on the server is working properly, but in Eclipse I got an error that I can not eliminate.

I have this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'deployment'. One of '{ear-subdeployments-isolated, deployment, sub-deployment, module}' is expected.   jboss-deployment-structure.xml  /spring-eap6-quickstart/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 2
```

That indicates error on deployment tag.

My jboss-deployment structure xml is:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
            <module name="com.h2database.h2"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

When I changed deployment structure to:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:2.0">
```

this change in eclipse corrects the error, but then the application does not work on OpenShift server.

I realize that the problem is in the setup, but I do not know how to overcome problem. Did anyone knows what I have to do? Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml is absolutely valid when using urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0. Unfortunately there are errors in the jbossas deployment-structure scheme and thus Eclipse will complain:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-15311

Bumping the version of the referred scheme to 2.0 fixes it in Eclipse by referring an inexistent scheme, 2.0 does not exist yet. Thus OpenShift will then fail. There's currently 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. The upcoming 2.0 should fix the scheme and thus have Eclipse validating properly. But we're not there yet unfortunately. I suggest that you simply turn the validation off, either all or only the scheme validation: Window->Preferences->Validation:

[image: validation preferences]

Answer (score 1):

update your xml to define the namespace, ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jds:jboss-deployment-structure xmlns:jds="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.dom4j" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jds:jboss-deployment-structure>
```